# Eigenvalues of the linear map $X\mapsto BX+XB$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $V = M_{2,2}(\mathbb{C})$, the vector space of all $2 × 2$-matrices over $\mathbb{C}$. Consider the matrix $$B= \left[   \begin{array}{ c c }      0 & 2 \\      0 & 0   \end{array} \right] $$ Let $f : V → V$ be the function given by $f(X) = BX + XB$ for all $X ∈ V$.
Determine the eigenvalues of the map $f$ and find the dimension of each of its
non-zero eigenspaces. 
Determine whether or not $f$ is diagonalisable.

I've been trying this question for a while and have no idea what to do, can someone please explain how do this step by step.
Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It's clear that $f$ is a linear transformation between finite dimensional vector spaces. In particular, it's not hard to see that the matrix representation of $[f]$ is a $4\times 4$ matrix. If we choose the basis 
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}=\left\{
e_1=
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
0& 0
\end{pmatrix},
e_2=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1\\
0& 0
\end{pmatrix},
e_3=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
1& 0
\end{pmatrix},
e_4=
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0& 1
\end{pmatrix}
\right\}
\end{align}
then we see that $[f]_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}}$ is given by
\begin{align}
[f]_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}} = ([f(e_1)]_\mathcal{B}\ \ [f(e_2)]_\mathcal{B}\ \ [f(e_3)]_\mathcal{B}\ \  [f(e_4)]_\mathcal{B}).
\end{align}

Observe
\begin{align}
f(e_1) =& 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 2e_2,\ \ f(e_2) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} \\
f(e_3) =& \begin{pmatrix}
2 & 0\\
0 & 2
\end{pmatrix} = 2e_1+2e_4,\ \ f(e_4) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 2\\
0 & 0
\end{pmatrix} = 2e_2 
\end{align}
then we have
\begin{align}
[f]_{\mathcal{B}\rightarrow \mathcal{B}} = 
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0& 2& 0\\
2 & 0& 0& 2\\
0 & 0& 0& 0\\
0 & 0& 2& 0
\end{pmatrix}.
\end{align}

I will leave the rest to the reader.

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can the Matrix representation that you've calculated for $f$ now be used to calculate the eigenvalues?

Comment: Yes. The was the purpose for finding the matrix representation.

Comment: I have calculated 2 eigenvalues to be 1 and -1, could you please verify these for me.

Comment: never mind, I've found there are no eigenvalues

Comment: @Hassan Of course there are...

Comment: Could you please explain how

Comment: @Hassan $e_2$ and $e_1-e_4$ are (obvious even without Jacky's matrix representation) eigenvectors ... And to see that $f$ is not diagonalizable observe that $f^3(e_3)=0$

Comment: Ok I can see why they're eigenvectors now, but how do I determine the eigenvalues?

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what "eigenvalue" **means**?  The direct calculation is pretty straight forward:

Let $X= \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}$
Then $f(x)= BX+ XB= \begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}+ \begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}0 & 2 \\ 0 & 0 \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}2c & 2a+ 2d \\ 0 & 2c\end{bmatrix}$.

A number, $\lambda$, is an Eigenvalue for F if and only if $\begin{bmatrix}2c & 2a+ 2d \\ 0 & 2c\end{bmatrix}= \lambda\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ c & d \end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}\lambda a & \lambda b \\ \lambda c & \lambda d\end{bmatrix}$.

So we must have $2c= \lambda a$, $2a+ 2d= \lambda b$, $\lambda c= 0$, and $\lambda d= 2c$.  Look at $\lambda c= 0$.  Either $\lambda= 0$ or $c= 0$.

If $\lambda$ is not 0 Then we must have $c= 0$ and the other equations become $\lambda a= 0$, $\lambda d= 0$, and $2a+ 2b= \lambda b$.  With $\lambda$ not 0, that gives a= d= 0 and then b= 0.  That is the "trivial solution" so that any non-zero number is **not** an eigenvalue.  If $\lambda= 0$ then 2c= 0, and 2a+ 2d= 0, so that d= -a while b can be any number.

The only eigenvalue is 0 with corresponding eigenvectors of the form $\begin{bmatrix}a & b \\ 0 & -a\end{bmatrix}= a\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1\end{bmatrix}+ b\begin{bmatrix}0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{bmatrix}$

Answer (score 1):

To find the eigenvalues, we set up 
$$
BX + XB = \lambda X.
$$
Then the equation becomes 
$$
(B-\lambda I) X + XB = 0.
$$
Let $M_{ B-\lambda I}$ be the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module provided by $B-\lambda I$ and $M_{-B}$ be the $\mathbb{C}[x]$-module provided by $-B$. 
Then the solution to this equation can be regarded as 
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[x]} (M_{ B-\lambda I}, M_{-B}).
$$
Since we have
$$
M_{ B-\lambda I} \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]/(x+\lambda)^2, \ \ M_{-B} \simeq \mathbb{C}[x]/x^2,
$$
Then nonzero solutions exist if and only if $\lambda = 0$.

Moreover, in case $\lambda =0$, we have the following isomorphism as $\mathbb{C}[x]$-modules:
$$
\mathrm{Hom}_{\mathbb{C}[x]} (M_{ B-\lambda I}, M_{-B})\simeq \mathbb{C}[x]/x^2.
$$
Thus, the only eigenvalue of $f$ is $0$ with corresponding $2$-dimensional eigenspace. This shows that $f$ is not diagonalizable.